# Trouble deploying EJB application to JBoss when implementing persistence

Tags: jboss, persistence, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to implement EJB persistence, but I'm having trouble deploying my application to JBoss. In my application I have the session bean TeamMgr, which looks like this:

```
package ejb;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import domain.TeamBean;

@Stateless
@Local(ITeamMgrLocal.class)
@Remote(ITeamMgrRemote.class)
public class TeamMgr implements ITeamMgrLocal, ITeamMgrRemote {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="team_workouts") private EntityManager manager;

public TeamMgr() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void addMember(int tid, int ub) {
System.out.println("In TeamMgr.addMember()...");
System.out.println("New Member ID: " + ub);
System.out.println("Leaving TeamMgr.addMember()...");
}

@Override
public void createTeam(int m1, int m2, int m3, int m4, int m5, String tn) {
System.out.println("In TeamMgr.createTeam()...");
System.out.println("Persisting team name: " + tn);
TeamBean tb = new TeamBean(tn, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5);
manager.persist(tb);
System.out.println("Leaving TeamMgr.createTeam()...");
}
}
```

My persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="team_workouts">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Finally, I have a mysql-ds.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>MySqlDS</jndi-name>
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://mysql-hostname:3306/team_workouts</connection-url>
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
<user-name>root</user-name>
<password>admin</password>
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
<metadata>
<type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
</metadata>
</local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

When I try to run my application on the JBoss server, I get the following error messages in the Eclipse console:

```
14:31:01,151 INFO [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@477660127{vfszip:/Applications/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/TeamWorkoutEJB.jar/}
14:31:01,315 INFO [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@477660127{vfszip:/Applications/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/TeamWorkoutEJB.jar/}
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: TeamWorkoutEJB.jar
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=GoalMgr,service=EJB3
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] with dependencies:
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] and demands:
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] and supplies:
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:GoalMgr/remote-ejb.IGoalMgrRemote
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] Class:ejb.IGoalMgrRemote
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:GoalMgr/local
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:GoalMgr/remote
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:GoalMgr/local-ejb.IGoalMgrLocal
14:31:01,385 INFO [JBossASKernel] Class:ejb.IGoalMgrLocal
14:31:01,386 INFO [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=GoalMgr,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: TeamWorkoutEJB.jar
14:31:01,386 INFO [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=TeamMgr,service=EJB3
14:31:01,386 INFO [JBossASKernel] with dependencies:
14:31:01,386 INFO [JBossASKernel] and demands:
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] and supplies:
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] Class:ejb.ITeamMgrRemote
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:TeamMgr/local
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:TeamMgr/remote
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] Class:ejb.ITeamMgrLocal
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:TeamMgr/remote-ejb.ITeamMgrRemote
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] jndi:TeamMgr/local-ejb.ITeamMgrLocal
14:31:01,387 INFO [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=TeamMgr,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: TeamWorkoutEJB.jar
14:31:01,388 INFO [EJB3EndpointDeployer] Deploy AbstractBeanMetaData@2050a472{name=jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=TeamMgr,service=EJB3_endpoint bean=org.jboss.ejb3.endpoint.deployers.impl.EndpointImpl properties=[container] constructor=null autowireCandidate=true}
14:31:01,534 INFO [EJB3EndpointDeployer] Deploy AbstractBeanMetaData@78c0d6e5{name=jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=GoalMgr,service=EJB3_endpoint bean=org.jboss.ejb3.endpoint.deployers.impl.EndpointImpl properties=[container] constructor=null autowireCandidate=true}
14:31:01,951 INFO [PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts
14:31:02,262 INFO [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
14:31:02,298 INFO [Environment] Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
14:31:02,304 INFO [Environment] hibernate.properties not found
14:31:02,309 INFO [Environment] Bytecode provider name : javassist
14:31:02,318 INFO [Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
14:31:02,450 INFO [Version] Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
14:31:02,458 INFO [Version] Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA
14:31:02,529 INFO [Ejb3Configuration] Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: team_workouts
...]
14:31:02,548 WARN [Ejb3Configuration] Persistence provider caller does not implement the EJB3 spec correctly. PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader() is null.
14:31:02,706 INFO [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: domain.UserBean
14:31:02,951 INFO [EntityBinder] Bind entity domain.UserBean on table user
14:31:03,023 INFO [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: domain.TeamBean
14:31:03,023 INFO [EntityBinder] Bind entity domain.TeamBean on table team
14:31:03,025 INFO [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: domain.GoalBean
14:31:03,026 INFO [EntityBinder] Bind entity domain.GoalBean on table goal
14:31:03,041 INFO [Version] Hibernate Validator 3.1.0.GA
14:31:03,108 INFO [HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister] Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
14:31:03,203 INFO [ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
14:31:03,207 INFO [InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider] Using provided datasource
14:31:03,784 WARN [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:225)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:195)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:633)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:267)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:622)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:404)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:381)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:46)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:301)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2260)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:787)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:207)
... 71 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:344)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2181)
... 81 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-hostname
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:850)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1201)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1154)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:246)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:293)
... 82 more
14:31:03,788 WARN [SettingsFactory] Could not obtain connection metadata
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Unable to get managed connection for MySqlDS; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for MySqlDS)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:95)
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:46)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:301)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for MySqlDS
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:441)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:381)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
... 62 more
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:225)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:195)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:633)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:267)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:622)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:404)
... 66 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2260)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:787)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:207)
... 71 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=GoalMgr,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts' **")
Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=GoalMgr,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=GoalMgr,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=TeamMgr,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts' **")
Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=TeamMgr,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.j2ee:jar=TeamWorkoutEJB.jar,name=TeamMgr,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "PreInstall")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts' **
Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts' **
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what's causing this?

Comment: please select all your code and click the code button in the editor to make your code legible.

Answer (score 2):

Your datasource couldn't get properly created and the cause is in the log:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-hostname
```

The host used in the JDBC connection string can't get reached. Either put the host name in a DNS or in the `hosts` file or use its IP.

Comment: You're exactly right!  I replaced mysql-hostname with localhost and it's working now.  Thank you!

Comment: @Zelda You're welcome. And feel free to accept this answer then (the green tick under the vote counter on the left) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Are you sure you have access to your database?

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=#team_workouts" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
```

Did you specify the MySQL hibernate dialect in your persistence.xml file? Like:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
```